# How to find hot spot in a C or C++ program?

Tags: c++, c

I want to find hot spots in MiBench benchmark suit programs. I also want to find out which variables and functions are most called during execution of a program. I've searched for a free useful tool but i couldn't find what i want. Is there any free tool for this purpose?

Answer (score 3):

Use `gprof`, you can compile you code with `-pg`, such as

```
gcc test.cpp -pg -o test
./test
gprof -b -A -p -q test gmon.out
```

Then it will print all the stat info of the code, read [gprof documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/) to understand better.

Also if you want to see all the detail of the code, such as cache miss rate or something else like that, you can try [tau](http://www.cs.uoregon.edu/research/tau/home.php).